# Having Three AUTO-INC fields in mySQL or emulating this with TRIGGERS

Tags: mysql, triggers, auto-increment

I have a table called **contents** which contains the ingredients of a specific chemical formula. As suspected, if the ingredients are added to the formula in the wrong order, the formula is not successful.
So, consider that I have six fields:

> id | formula_id | ingredient_id | quantity | item_id | add_id

Where:

```
id = the PK and primary index
formula_id = a repeating integer depending on the id of the formula
ingredient_id = the PK from the "ingredients" table
quantity = self-explanatory
item_id = the UNIQUE one-based item id of that ingredient as it pertains to the formula
add_id = the UNIQUE zero-based index of the order in which this ingredient is added to the formula
```

So, as I am modifying formulas, and adding ingredients, I want to make sure that both the item_id and add_id are incremental integers that are handled by mySQL rather than the PHP code and in a manner that they can be modified later on (should the order of the added ingredients need to be adjusted).

Since I cannot find a decent TRIGGER writing tutorial nor anything about having three AUTO-INC fields, where two only increment based on the "formula_id", I come here and ask for your help.

Comment: All of this is a little bit abstract, but my *guess* is your *real* problem is that you use the same entity to model both a formula and an ingredient. I think you should have two different entities here, with a many-to-many relashion-ship, probably adding the "ingredient position" as an attribute to that relationship. That way you shouldn't need *three* auto_increment ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, I've discovered that it's more my terminology that's incorrect than methodology. What I should have been looking for was a way to create a `UNIQUE INDEX` based on other fields.

Hence, the solution to my problems is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE `chem`.`formulas` 
DROP INDEX `item_id`, 
DROP INDEX `add_id`, 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `item_id` (`id`, `formula_id`, `ingredient_id`), 
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `add_id` (`id`, `formula_id`, `ingredient_id`);
```